# Getting same prediction with tensorflow on every example

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I have the following code where I am training a neural network on the MNIST dataset. Then, with the trained network I am trying to predict the values in `test_inputs`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from math import trunc
from subprocess import check_output

def make_one_hot(m):
    result = pd.DataFrame((np.asarray(m)[:,None] == np.arange(10)).astype(int))
    return result

train_data = pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv", delimiter=',')
train_labels = make_one_hot(train_data.ix[:, 0])
train_inputs = train_data.ix[:, 1:]
test_inputs = pd.read_csv("../input/test.csv", delimiter=',')    

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y,1e-10,1.0)), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cross_entropy)


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for _ in range(1000):
  batch_xs = train_inputs.sample(n=100)
  batch_ys = train_labels.sample(n=100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
result = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: test_inputs})

f = open("results.csv","w+")
f.write("ImageId,Label\n")
for i in range(0, len(result)):
  x = 0
  for j in range(0, 10):
      if(result.item(i, j) == 1):
          x = j
  f.write("{},{}\n".format(i+1, x))
```

However, the network always predicts the digit the same digit for all examples, regardless of the inputs.

The digit itself changes, sometimes it's `1`, other times`6` or `7` but all the examples get the same digit for the same run.

Any idea what could be wrong with it?

**EDIT**:

I fixed the indentation of the last line(which was wrong) but still the result has the same label for all test examples.

Comment: Did you try printing the training / dev loss with steps? Also, why aren't you using [`softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)?

Comment: "Did you try printing the training / dev loss with steps?" No, I haven't. How can I do that? "Also, why aren't you using softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits" Use this where?

Comment: also, I think that taking `batch_xs = train_inputs.sample()` and `batch_ys = train_labels.sample()` might lead to non-correlated inputs and labels, which won't lead to good learning... try `batch_ys = train_labels.loc[batch_xs.index]`.

Comment: but I think that the main issue is what @jack6e pointed out

Comment: @PietroTortella thanks that was actually the main issue

Answer (score 2):

*Edited in response to OP edits*

I still think you are meaning to use `x` in your `f.write` iteration. Right now you are not printing to your file anything other than the value of your `i` iteration and your `j` iteration, but not actually any of your results.

Are you trying to do something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(result)):
    x = 0
    for j in range(0, 10):
        if(result.item(i, j) == 1):
            x = j
            f.write("{},{}\n".format(i+1, x))
```

Or maybe:

```
for i in range(0, len(result)):

    for j in range(0, 10):
        x = result.item(i, j)
        f.write("{},{}\n".format(i+1, x))
```

*Original response*

*You need to fix your indentation:*

```
for j in range(0, 10):
    if(result.item(i, j) == 1):
        x = j
    f.write("{},{}\n".format(i+1, j))
```

*so that the `f.write` command falls under the `for j` loop. Right now you are writing the last `j` value, which in a `range(0,10)` is always `9` after the loop runs, which means every `i` image_id gets the label `9`.
Also, what are you doing with `x`? You first set `x = 0` and then `x = j` based on a condition, but never actually use it.*

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty stupid of me. I fixed the indentation but the result is the same.

Comment: Thank you. I had edited the question incorrectly. Now I changed it. The purpose was to print `x` at the end of the second for loop. However, the problem where I get the same answer for all the examples persists. I think it has to do with the machine learning rather than the alignment.

Answer (score 2):

The initialization of the variables will not allow the network to train. Having both biases and Weights initialized as zero will lead to no training as the gradients are always zero.

Use truncated normal with mean not equal to zero (around 0.1 is good).
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/truncated_normal

And the biases as ones. This will help the network to train as now the gradients won't be zero.

Comment: Ok, I used `truncated_normal` instead of `zeros` but the result is still the same.